# Class object not returning value

Tags: python, oop

```
class Friend:
    all = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.__fname = None
        self.__lname = None
        self.__fid = None

    @property
    def fname(self):
        return self.__fname

    @fname.setter
    def fname(self, value):
        self.__fname = value
    
    @property
    def lname(self):
        return self.__lname

    @lname.setter
    def lname(self, value):
        self.__lname = value
    
    @property
    def fid(self):
        return self.__fid

    @fid.setter
    def fid(self, value):
        self.__fid = value

#DB Class
class db_friend()
    def db_load_friend(self, obj, fname,lname):
        obj.fname = fname
        obj.lname  = lname
        obj.fid = "XYZ"
        
        obj.all.append(obj)

# function that acts on the friend class

def manage_friend():
    fname = "Joe"
    lname = "Root"
    objfriend = Friend()
    db_friend.db_load_friend(objfriend, fname,lname)
    print (objfriend.fname) # this is not working
    print (objfriend.fid) #this is not working
    
    for user in objfriend.all:
        print (objfriend.fid) #this is working
```

Both objfriend.fname and objfriend.fid is printing no value. I am trying to load the objfriend object by passing to the db_load_friend method of the db class. I am able to see the values if I loop through the "all" variable. May I know why this is not working or using the static variable "all" is the only way to do it?

Comment: You need to create an instance of `db_friend`.

Comment: You should be getting an error from `db_friend.db_load_friend(objfriend, fname,lname)` because you didn't pass enough arguments. You're missing the `self` argument.

Comment: `class db_friend()` is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: Why are you using a second class to set the attributes in the `Friend` class? Why not make `fname` and `lname` parameters to `Friend.__init__()`?

Comment: As an aside, your `class Friend:` is not implemented idiomatically, remove all those pointless getters and setters and just use regular attributes in `__init__`. Also, as others have pointed out, your contructor should probably accept the values for those attributes.

Comment: Classes and instances of them don't return values, so your question isn't clear. Please add code to to it to make it [mre] — i.e. something others can run simply by copying and pasting into a script file on their own systems.

Comment: This code has obvious syntax errors.  Please post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `db_friend` so you can call the `db_load_friend()` method:

```
def manage_friend():
    fname = "Joe"
    lname = "Root"
    objfriend = Friend()
    objdbfriend = db_friend()
    objdbfriend.db_load_friend(objfriend, fname,lname)
    print (objfriend.fname)
    print (objfriend.fid)
    
    for user in objfriend.all:
        print (objfriend.fid) #this is working
```

Or, since `db_load_friend()` doesn't need to use `self`, you could make it a static method.

```
class db_friend()
    @staticmethod
    def db_load_friend(obj, fname,lname):
        obj.fname = fname
        obj.lname  = lname
        obj.fid = "XYZ"
        
        obj.all.append(obj)
```